# Generate unique words from 2 different array letters

Tags: javascript

```
word1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
word2 = ['x','y','z'];
```

I want to generate **unique words** with the combination of these seven letters, but the condition is abcd and xyz order should not change. It must have 7 letters and no duplicate letters.

For example

```
 axbyczd - Correct
 xyabczd - Correct
 xayzbcd - Correct 

 acdxbyz - Wrong //because letter b is not in order by the position. 
 aybcdxz - Wrong //because letter y is not in order by the position.
```

I want the better solution in **Javascript**.

My solution is here 
https://jsfiddle.net/balaphp/5ht2eoh3/

Comment: Show what have you tried.

Comment: What should be the length of the unique word? i.e. how many characters should it have

Comment: Hi @hindmost This is the one i have tried
https://jsfiddle.net/3c720te4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
// Return an array of all the possible words made from weaving `word1` and `word2`.
function combine( word1, word2 ) {
    // The resulting array.
    var words = [];
    // Length of the words to put in `words`.
    var len = word1.length + word2.length;
    // Array of the positions of each letter of `word1`.
    // For  instance, if  `word1` is  "abcd" and  `word2`is "xyz",
    // then the  final word will  be 7 length. Therefore,  to keep
    // "a", "b", "c" and "d" in that  order, the "a" can be put in
    // position from  0 to 3, the  "b" in position from  a+1 to 4,
    // the "c" in position  from b+1 to 5 and the  "d" from c+1 to
    // 6.
    var pos = [];
    // Array of the letters of the final word. Undefined items are
    // free places for letters of `word2`.
    var word = [];

    // Recursive function.
    // First, it calls itself until all the letters of `word1` are set.
    // Then, place the letters of `word2` in the left spaces.
    function find() {
        var a, b, j, k, currentWord;
        if (pos.length == word1.length) {
            // Letters of `word1` are now spreaded. Let's place the letters of `word2`.
            currentWord = word.slice();
            for (j = 0 ; j < word2.length ; j++) {
                for (k = 0 ; k < len ; k++) {
                    if (currentWord[k]) continue;
                    currentWord[k] = word2.charAt(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
            words.push( currentWord.join('') );
        } else {
            // Spread letters of `word1`.
            // The current letter to place is `word1.charAt( pos.length )`.
            // `a` is the first possible position for the current letter of `word1`.
            // `b` is the last possible position.
            a = 0;  // The first letter can be set at position 0.
            if ( pos.length > 0 ) {
                // If  it  is  not  the first  letter,  the  first
                // available position  is the current  position of
                // the previous letter, plus one.
                a = pos[pos.length - 1] + 1;
            }
            // The last position must keep egnough space for remaining letters.
            b = len - word1.length + pos.length;
            // Put the current letter on every possible places.
            for (j = a ; j <= b ; j++) {
                // Put the current letter at position `j`.
                pos.push( j );
                word[j] = word1.charAt( pos.length - 1 );
                // Recurse to place next letters.
                find();
                // Backtrack for next case.
                word[j] = undefined;
                pos.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    // Starting recursion.
    find();

    return words;
}

// Here is a example of how you can use the `combine` function.
function start() {
    var words = combine( 'abcd', 'xyz' );
    document.getElementById('out').textContent = words.join("\n");
}
```

View it in action on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pafbvru2/).

The main idea is to place first the letters of word1, then the letters of word2.

Comment: Tolokoban Please add comments so that someone else looking for answers in the future will understand. Thanks.

Comment: @balaphp I've edited the code to add comments as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks @tolokoban. This is my solution please see this.
https://jsfiddle.net/3c720te4/

Comment: But @tolokoban still yours is the best. mine taking 38ms yours only 1 ms...
https://jsfiddle.net/balaphp/pafbvru2/1/

Answer (score 1):

A version with brute force, first get all combinations and then look for the rules in `arrays.every(...)` before pushing to the result set. This works for more than two arrays.

```js
function combine(arrays) {

    function c(l, r) {
        var i, ll;
        if (!l.length) {
            arrays.every(function (a) {
                return a.every(function (b) {
                    var p = r.indexOf(b);
                    if (p > this.last) {
                        this.last = p;
                        return true;
                    }
                }, { last: -1 });
            }) && result.push(r);
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            ll = l.slice();
            c(ll, r.concat(ll.splice(i, 1)));
        }
    }

    var array = arrays.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b); }),
        result = [];

    c(array, []);
    return result;
}

var result1 = combine([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]);
var result2 = combine([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], [1, 2]]);

document.write('<pre>length: ' + result1.length + ' ' + JSON.stringify(result1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>length: ' + result2.length + ' ' + JSON.stringify(result2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function processPermute(numberArr,beginLetters) {

  var permArr = [];
  var usedChars = [];

  function permute(input) {

var i, ch;

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if(usedChars.length == 0 || beginLetters.indexOf(usedChars[0]) !== -1){
    ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
    usedChars.push(ch);
    if (input.length == 0) {
      permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
    }
    permute(input,beginLetters);
    input.splice(i, 0, ch);
    usedChars.pop();
  }
}
  };
   permute(numberArr);
   return permArr

}

function validateRule(wordNumber, word) {
  var wordStr = word.join('');
  var wordCheckArr = [];
  
  if(!(wordNumber[0] === 'a' || wordNumber[0] === 'x')){
return false;
  }  

  for (var i = 0; i < wordNumber.length; i++) {
if (word.indexOf(wordNumber[i]) !== -1) {
  wordCheckArr.push(wordNumber[i]);
}
  }
  return (wordCheckArr.join('') === wordStr);
}

function findWords(words, rules) {

  var letters = [];
  var beginLetters = [];
  words.forEach(function(word) {
beginLetters.push(word[0]);
letters = letters.concat(word);
  });
  var allWords = processPermute(letters,beginLetters);

  var rightWords = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < allWords.length; j++) {

var result = 1;

for (var k = 0; k < rules.length; k++) {
  if (validateRule(allWords[j], rules[k])) {
    result *= 1;
  } else {
    result *= 0;
  }
}

if (result) {
  rightWords.push(allWords[j].join(''));
}

  }
  return rightWords;

}
var words = findWords([
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['x', 'y', 'z']
], [
  ['a', 'b', 'c','d'],
  ['x', 'y', 'z']
]);


document.write('<pre>'+words.join("\n")+'</pre>');
   //min execution time 10ms
```